# Bash script: How to read values from a JSON file and use them as input

Tags: json, bash, function, grep

I am trying to parse values from JSON file that takes the following form (config.json):

```
[{
  "gain": "90",
  "exposure": "850",
  "whitebalanceR": "120",
  "whitebalanceG": "185",
  "whitebalanceB": "100",
  "Snap": "True"
}
]
```

I parse each individual string like this (app.sh):

```
grep -o '"gain": "[^"]*' config.json | grep -o '[^"]*$'
grep -o '"exposure": "[^"]*' config.json | grep -o '[^"]*$'
grep -o '"whitebalanceR": "[^"]*' config.json | grep -o '[^"]*$'
grep -o '"whitebalanceG": "[^"]*' config.json | grep -o '[^"]*$'
grep -o '"whitebalanceB": "[^"]*' config.json | grep -o '[^"]*$'
```

This will output the value of the string in the terminal
I would like to use the value for each string as input to some function like this:

```
./someFunc -w '${whitebalanceR} ${whitebalanceG} ${whitebalanceG}' -ax6 -s ${exposure} -g ${gain} -i 1 -o -a -6
```

But it fails to run? What am I doing wrong? and how to actually use the JSON string as input to a function in bash?
Much appreciated

Comment: Why not use [jq](https://linuxhint.com/bash_jq_command/)?

Comment: I initially tried jq but I was getting some error. But now it is working fine for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, use bash is a bad idea for parsing JSON. But, if you have no choice, use `jq` as [Tranbi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13525512/tranbi) suggested:

```bash
gain=$( jq -r '.[] | .gain' config.json; )
echo $gain
```

`-r` option is required to print the value without quotes.

Hope that helps!